# Custom render engine - creating material previews with OpenGL?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, opengl, bgl

I'm working on a custom render engine through a Python addon that uses the `bgl` module for most of its rendering. `bl_use_preview` is enabled on the engine to let it create material previews, and `bl_use_gpu_context` is enabled so that it can use the OpenGL context in its `render` method. It works great for final renders, but not so well for material previews.

Particularly, I've found that `bgl` function calls create strange effects in the 3D view when previews are generated while in solid mode. This ranges from filling the screen with black to giving it a lighter tint to making parts of the model translucent, etc. There are also bugs in the previews themselves if they're generated in rapid succession, but I haven't tested this as much.

It seems like any `bgl` calls at all result in this behavior, including functions like `glGetError`, which should have no effect on rendering as far as I'm aware. The following self-contained code demonstrates this (if you comment out `glGetError()`, it'll do nothing, but otherwise, generating material previews through the panel will make the 3D view glitchy on the next draw):

```
import bpy
import bgl


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomRenderEngine)
    bpy.types.MATERIAL_PT_preview.COMPAT_ENGINES.add(CustomRenderEngine.bl_idname)


def unregister():
    bpy.types.MATERIAL_PT_preview.COMPAT_ENGINES.remove(CustomRenderEngine.bl_idname)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomRenderEngine)


class CustomRenderEngine(bpy.types.RenderEngine):
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM"
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_use_preview = True
    bl_use_gpu_context = True

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        pass

    def render(self, depsgraph: bpy.types.Depsgraph):
        bgl.glGetError() # i put this in render(), but it has the same effect in __init__, __del__, etc

    def view_update(self, context, depsgraph):
        pass

    def view_draw(self, context, depsgraph):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Are `bl_use_preview` and `bl_use_gpu_context` simply incompatible? I'm aware that `bgl` is deprecated (using it because it has some features that `gpu` still seems to lack), so I understand if that's also part of the issue. Is there anything else I can do here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.